# kubernetes - migrate form calico to flannel

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, calico

I have a K8S cluster versioned 1.11.

I have calico installed as cni plugin.
I need to replace it with flannel.

I found guides online how to migrate from flannel to calico but not the other way around.

Down any one have a tip/idea how to get by this?

Is it even possible migrating from Calico to flannel?

Thanks

Comment: Plus the kubernetes version is so old. Why waste time to migrate the CNI plugin which you can spend less time to start up a latest kubernetes cluster (1.17) in 15 minutes with another 5 minutes to set flannel ready.

Comment: Remember if you want to upgrade kuberentes later, you have to upgrade minor version only, so 1.11 has to be migrated to 1.12 first, then 1.13, until 1.17. I don't think you should go this route.

Comment: any why calico doesn't work for you, any special features you are looking for in flannel only?

Comment: We are using F5 - cni integration and for some reason it is not working properly with calico and flannel integration with F5 is smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Migrating a cluster from Flannel to Calico is feasible but migration from Calico to Flannel is not supported.

This is mentioned in the documentation provided by [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.9/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/migration-from-flannel):

> **Rollback**: Migration from Calico to flannel is not supported.